# travis script deployment timeout

Tags: travis-ci

I have the following deploy section in my `.travis.yml`

```
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: bash scripts/deploy.sh
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    all_branches: true
```

The problem is that `bash scripts/deploy.sh` can take anywhere between 7 and 10 minutes meaning that this occasionally goes over the 10 minute timeout that travis has by default. But not to worry - travis offers [travis_wait](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received). Here is my updated `.travis.yml`.

```
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: travis_wait 30 bash scripts/deploy.sh
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    all_branches: true
```

Problem is, this fails with `Script failed with status 127`.

Is it possible to use `travis_wait` within script deployment?

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this by wrapping my deploy command (npm run deploy) in a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

npm run deploy &

# Output to the screen every 9 minutes to prevent a travis timeout
export PID=$!
while [[ `ps -p $PID | tail -n +2` ]]; do
  echo 'Deploying'
  sleep 540
done
```